# What is a way to get a URL mapping for child resources

Tags: grails, url-mapping

I have a mapping of Color and Shades. Each color can have multiple shades.

How can I have a mapping like: "`color/5/shades`". With this I wish to show all shades for color Id 5.

Currently my mapping is like this:

```
    "/colors"(controller: "color", parseRequest: true){
        action = [GET: "list"]
    }

    "/color/$id" (resource: "color"){
        constraints {
            id validator: {
                !(it in ['create', 'detail')
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily mapped when [Grails 2.3 is concerned](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/single.html#restfulMappings).

```
//Grails 2.3
"/color"(resources:'color') {
  "/shades"(resources:"shade")
}
```

then you can access `/color/${id}/shades`

When **Grails 2.2.4 or below** is concerned, I think your `UrlMapping` can be optimized more like below:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        "/colors/$id?/$shades?" (resource: "color"){
            constraints {
                shades validator: {
                    it in ['shades']
                }
                id validator: {it.isNumber()}
            }
        }

        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
    }
}


//controller action corresponding
//GET 
def show(){
   if(params.id){
       if(params.shades){
          //If both id and shades present in URL
          //then getShades
          //maps to "/colors/5/shades"
          getShades()
       } else {
          //If only id provided then GET color
          //maps to "/colors/5"
          getColor()
       }
   } else {
       //If id not provided the list all colors
       //maps to "/colors"
       listColors()
   }
}

private def getShades(){...}
private def getColor(){...}
private def listColors(){...}
```

**Note**
Note to remove the default mapping provided by grails

```
//remove
"/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
    constraints {
      // apply constraints here
    }
}
```

**Rationale behind removing the default entry:-**
You do not the other validator for (`create` and `detail`) if you remove this entry, assuming you are not using the default entry for REST services.

Comment: hmm I don't think I can remove the default mapping provided by grails. If I remove that then lot of my other controllers break, including mappings for spring security

Comment: @Anthony Thats ok. I think I took care of it. Look at the validator for `id`. :) Let me know if any portion of the answer is not understandable. I would be happy to clarify.